# Email enviado, chega sempre como spam, no SquirrelMail com Postfix no debian 8

Tags: email, linux

Instalei o postfix e o SquirrelMail em meu servidor para receber e enviar emails, acontece é que os emails sempre chegam ao destinatário sempre na caixa de spam.

**Qual configuração devo fazer para que o email chegue normalmente?**